# Stan model will not compile in R or Rstudio

Tags: c++, r, stan, rstan

I am having a strange problem that I have not encountered before while using R, Rstudio, or stan. I am not able to get any model to compile in stan. I am pretty confident it is not the models. trivial models in brms do not compile either. Whereas rstanarm models have no problem, being pre-compiled, as I understand. Likewise, similar models compile without problems on another computer. So, something is wrong with my configurations, but that stuff is above my understanding. I have tried the old delete everything and re-install trick to no avail. I am worried that I deleted something without realizing it while cleaning up files.

I am on a PC with windows 10 pro. I have R 4.0.4. Rstudio 1.4.1103.

Everytime I try to compile a stan model I get the following output:

```
make cmd is
  make -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-40~1.4/etc/x64/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-40~1.4/share/make/winshlib.mk" CXX='$(CXX14) $(CXX14STD)' CXXFLAGS='$(CXX14FLAGS)' CXXPICFLAGS='$(CXX14PICFLAGS)' SHLIB_LDFLAGS='$(SHLIB_CXX14LDFLAGS)' SHLIB_LD='$(SHLIB_CXX14LD)' SHLIB="file735032f41a17.dll" WIN=64 TCLBIN=64 OBJECTS="file735032f41a17.o"

make would use
if test "zfile735032f41a17.o" != "z"; then \
  if test -e "file735032f41a17-win.def"; then \
    echo "C:/rtools40/mingw64/bin/"g++  -shared -s -static-libgcc -o file735032f41a17.dll file735032f41a17-win.def file735032f41a17.o   "C:/Users/loren/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/rstan/lib/x64/libStanServices.a" -L"C:/Users/loren/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/StanHeaders/libs/x64" -lStanHeaders -L"C:/Users/loren/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/RcppParallel/lib/x64" -ltbb  -L"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-40~1.4/bin/x64" -lR ; \
    "C:/rtools40/mingw64/bin/"g++  -shared -s -static-libgcc -o file735032f41a17.dll file735032f41a17-win.def file735032f41a17.o   "C:/Users/loren/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/rstan/lib/x64/libStanServices.a" -L"C:/Users/loren/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/StanHeaders/libs/x64" -lStanHeaders -L"C:/Users/loren/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/RcppParallel/lib/x64" -ltbb  -L"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-40~1.4/bin/x64" -lR ; \
  else \
    echo EXPORTS > tmp.def; \
    "C:/rtools40/mingw64/bin/"nm file735032f41a17.o | sed -n 's/^.* [BCDRT] / /p' | sed -e '/[.]refptr[.]/d' -e '/[.]weak[.]/d' | sed 's/[^ ][^ ]*/"&"/g'  >> tmp.def; \
    echo "C:/rtools40/mingw64/bin/"g++  -shared -s -static-libgcc -o file735032f41a17.dll tmp.def file735032f41a17.o   "C:/Users/loren/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/rstan/lib/x64/libStanServices.a" -L"C:/Users/loren/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/StanHeaders/libs/x64" -lStanHeaders -L"C:/Users/loren/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/RcppParallel/lib/x64" -ltbb  -L"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-40~1.4/bin/x64" -lR ; \
    "C:/rtools40/mingw64/bin/"g++  -shared -s -static-libgcc -o file735032f41a17.dll tmp.def file735032f41a17.o   "C:/Users/loren/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/rstan/lib/x64/libStanServices.a" -L"C:/Users/loren/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/StanHeaders/libs/x64" -lStanHeaders -L"C:/Users/loren/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/RcppParallel/lib/x64" -ltbb  -L"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-40~1.4/bin/x64" -lR ; \
    rm -f tmp.def; \
  fi \
fi
Error in compileCode(f, code, language = language, verbose = verbose) : 
  C:/rtools40/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/loren/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/rstan/lib/x64/libStanServices.a(stan_fit.o):stan_fit.cpp:(.data$_ZZN5boost4math6detail9bessel_j0IeEET_S3_E2P1[_ZZN5boost4math6detail9bessel_j0IeEET_S3_E2P1]+0x0): multiple definition of `boost::math::detail::bessel_j0<long double>(long double)::P1'; file735032f41a17.o:file735032f41a17.cpp:(.rdata$_ZZN5boost4math6detail9bessel_j0IeEET_S3_E2P1[_ZZN5boost4math6detail9bessel_j0IeEET_S3_E2P1]+0x0): first defined hereC:/rtools40/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/loren/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/rstan/lib/x64/libStanServices.a(stan_fit.o):stan_fit.cpp:(.data$_ZZN5boost4math6detail9bessel_j0IeEET_S3_E2QS[_ZZN5boost4math6detail9bessel_j0IeEET_S3_E2QS]+0x0): multiple definition of `boost::math::detail::bessel_j0<long double>(long double)::QS'; file735032f41a17.o:file735032f41a
Error in sink(type = "output") : invalid connection
```

This is the first time I have asked a question in the forums. So, if I have not given you all the information you need, don't hesitate to ask for it. Thanks much for your help.

Seems this is common:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.4 (2021-02-15)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19041)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] rstan_2.21.2         StanHeaders_2.21.0-7 bayesplot_1.8.0      sjPlot_2.8.7         survminer_0.4.8     
 [6] ggpubr_0.4.0         survival_3.2-7       rstanarm_2.21.1      brms_2.14.4          Rcpp_1.0.6          
[11] finalfit_1.0.2       lubridate_1.7.9.2    reshape2_1.4.4       googlesheets4_0.2.0  forcats_0.5.1       
[16] stringr_1.4.0        dplyr_1.0.4          purrr_0.3.4          readr_1.4.0          tidyr_1.1.2         
[21] tibble_3.0.6         ggplot2_3.3.3        tidyverse_1.3.0     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
  [1] readxl_1.3.1         backports_1.2.1      plyr_1.8.6           igraph_1.2.6         splines_4.0.4       
  [6] crosstalk_1.1.1      TH.data_1.0-10       rstantools_2.1.1     inline_0.3.17        digest_0.6.27       
 [11] htmltools_0.5.1.1    rsconnect_0.8.16     magrittr_2.0.1       openxlsx_4.2.3       modelr_0.1.8        
 [16] RcppParallel_5.0.2   matrixStats_0.58.0   xts_0.12.1           sandwich_3.0-0       askpass_1.1         
 [21] prettyunits_1.1.1    colorspace_2.0-0     rvest_0.3.6          xfun_0.20            haven_2.3.1         
 [26] callr_3.5.1          crayon_1.4.1         jsonlite_1.7.2       lme4_1.1-26          zoo_1.8-8           
 [31] glue_1.4.2           gargle_0.5.0         gtable_0.3.0         emmeans_1.5.4        sjstats_0.18.1      
 [36] sjmisc_2.8.6         V8_3.4.0             car_3.0-10           pkgbuild_1.2.0       abind_1.4-5         
 [41] scales_1.1.1         mvtnorm_1.1-1        DBI_1.1.1            ggeffects_1.0.1      rstatix_0.7.0       
 [46] miniUI_0.1.1.1       performance_0.7.0    xtable_1.8-4         foreign_0.8-81       km.ci_0.5-2         
 [51] stats4_4.0.4         DT_0.17              htmlwidgets_1.5.3    httr_1.4.2           threejs_0.3.3       
 [56] ellipsis_0.3.1       mice_3.13.0          pkgconfig_2.0.3      loo_2.4.1            dbplyr_2.1.0        
 [61] effectsize_0.4.3     tidyselect_1.1.0     rlang_0.4.10         later_1.1.0.1        munsell_0.5.0       
 [66] cellranger_1.1.0     tools_4.0.4          cli_2.3.0            generics_0.1.0       sjlabelled_1.1.7    
 [71] broom_0.7.4          ggridges_0.5.3       fastmap_1.1.0        knitr_1.31           processx_3.4.5      
 [76] fs_1.5.0             zip_2.1.1            survMisc_0.5.5       nlme_3.1-152         mime_0.9            
 [81] projpred_2.0.2       xml2_1.3.2           compiler_4.0.4       shinythemes_1.2.0    rstudioapi_0.13     
 [86] gamm4_0.2-6          curl_4.3             ggsignif_0.6.0       reprex_1.0.0         statmod_1.4.35      
 [91] stringi_1.5.3        parameters_0.11.0    ps_1.5.0             Brobdingnag_1.2-6    lattice_0.20-41     
 [96] Matrix_1.3-2         nloptr_1.2.2.2       markdown_1.1         KMsurv_0.1-5         shinyjs_2.0.0       
[101] vctrs_0.3.6          pillar_1.4.7         lifecycle_1.0.0      bridgesampling_1.0-0 estimability_1.3    
[106] insight_0.13.0       data.table_1.13.6    httpuv_1.5.5         R6_2.5.0             promises_1.1.1      
[111] gridExtra_2.3        rio_0.5.16           codetools_0.2-18     boot_1.3-26          colourpicker_1.1.0  
[116] MASS_7.3-53          gtools_3.8.2         assertthat_0.2.1     openssl_1.4.3        withr_2.4.1         
[121] shinystan_2.5.0      multcomp_1.4-16      bayestestR_0.8.2     mgcv_1.8-33          parallel_4.0.4      
[126] hms_1.0.0            grid_4.0.4           coda_0.19-4          minqa_1.2.4          carData_3.0-4       
[131] googledrive_1.0.1    shiny_1.6.0          base64enc_0.1-3      dygraphs_1.1.1.6
```

The following very simple stan model elicits the above error

```
model <- "
  data{
    int<lower=0> N;
    vector[N] Y;
    vector[N] X;
  }

  parameters{
    real beta;
    real mu;
    real<lower=0> sigma;
  }

  model{
    Y ~ normal(mu + beta*X, sigma);

    mu ~ normal(0, 1);
    beta ~ normal(0, 1);
    sigma ~ gamma(0.1, 0.1);
  }"

stan_model(model_code = model)
```

Comment: Did you install rtools & correctly set the path: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/ . (rstanarm may work as it "Estimates previously compiled regression models" whereas in rstan each new model is compiled )

Comment: `multiple definition of boost::math::detail::bessel_j0...` is the most relevant part of the error message but it is going to be difficult to figure out what the problem is unless you can post some Stan code that triggers it.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I do believe I have Rtools installed and the path set correctly. As for stan code that triggers this...everything triggers this. I have added a stan model that elicits the error.

Comment: Gents, on a whim, I tried re-installing rstan. This solved the problem. The simple model above and more complicated models now compile. However, I get the following warning message: `Warning message:
In system(paste(CXX, ARGS), ignore.stdout = TRUE, ignore.stderr = TRUE) :
  'C:/rtools40/usr/mingw_/bin/g++' not found` Is this something I should worry about?

Comment: @MpirikL Don't worry about that warning message.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to stumble onto a solution. I re-installed rstan. I have no idea what the problem was or why this fixed it. If others would like to weigh in, that would be much appreciated. Thanks to those who put any thought into my query.

Comment: Your (gnu) make command has two -f options. That seems odd because the -f option specifies a make file and AFAIK there's usually only one needed. One way to debug a make command is to use -n option. Then you can inspect the build commands without running the build as a sense check. What does the make command look like now you have it working?